# Replace intensity voxel values with probabilities

Tags: python, csv, nifti

I would like to know how to replace the intensity values from the voxels of an image (`nifti`) by probability values (0-1) to generate a plot in colors. I have two files, the original image in `nifti` and the probabilities in a **CSV** (rows = voxels, column = probabilities).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the size of your .csv file is the same as your NIfTI volumes, then if the number of voxels is `n`, the number of rows in your .csv file should also be `n`. And if the NIfTI file is 3D (one volume), your .csv file should have only 1 column (more columns would correspond to different volumes in a 4D time series).

In this simple case you should be able to use `np.genfromtxt` for the csv file to read the probability and `nibabel` to read/write the NIfTI file:

```
import nibabel as nb;
import numpy as np;

probabilities = np.genfromtxt  ( 'myColumn.csv'               );
inFile        = nb.load        ( 'MyVolume.nii.gz'            );    
outFile       = nb.Nifti1Image ( probabilities, inFile.affine );
outFile.to_filename            ( 'MyProbs.nii.gz'             );
```

You may need to re-shape the probabilities array; in the absence of more specific information I have assumed it all fits.